# React Native не работает обновление приложения на девайсе

Tags: android, windows, mobile

Установил React Native на Windows 10. Всё сделано строго по инструкции на оф. сайте. Ошибок в ходе установок и настроек не было. Приложение успешно создаётся, и после запуска команды react-native run-android производится сборка и запуск на android-девайсе. Потом там загружается JS bundle, запускается тестовое приложение.

Но оно никак не обновляется и не реагирует на изменение index.android.js. Только если отключать сервер и всё перезапускать заново и ждать 3-4 минуты. Я встряхиваю телефон и жму Reload JS, но ничего не обновляется.

Заходил в Dev options и настраивал там сервер. Приложение ошибок не выдавало, я ставил IP компа и порт 8081, пробовал ставить localhost:8081. Пробовал использовать другой порт и перезапускать сервер. Но результат один и тот же. Не обновляется приложение в телефоне.
А на эмуляторе вообще не запускается.